# Reorder git history and preserving content rather than commit/patch

Tags: git

For example, with a git history like this

```
root-commit 1 @ day 1
+ d1

commit 2 @ day 3
- d1
+ d3

commit 3 @ day 2
- d3
+ d2
```

Two commits from day 2 and day 3 were out of order, and I want to swap them.
I would expect the result to be

```
root-commit 1 @ day 1
+ d1

commit 2 @ day 2
- d1
+ d2

commit 3 @ day 3
- d2
+ d3
```

The history is linear without any branches or merging. I tried to use rebase but it seems to be operating the existing commits (patches), which I'm going to discard, for example, the `- d1  + d3` commit. Rebasing will fail to apply due to conflict and requires manual resolve, which is not feasible for me.

The way I could think of is to do `git archive` (or `git diff` with the root commit) for all commits, order them and create a completely new history. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase is the wrong tool, but Git doesn't come with the right tool for your job, because that job is ... not something Git was ever designed to *do*.

Still, Git *can* do it.  It's just a matter of using the underlying components, rather than any of the top-level, user-facing ("porcelain") commands.

> The way I could think of is to do git archive (or git diff with the root commit) for all commits, order them and create a completely new history. Is there any better way to do this?

Using `git archive` would be *okay*, but it's more work than needed.  Using `git diff` against the root each time would be even more work than that, and less appropriate.

The simplest method is to use `git commit-tree`.  This a low-level ("plumbing") command that needs three inputs:

- It needs a *list of parent hash IDs*.  You'll pick, as your parent commit (singular), the root commit the first time, then the last commit you just made for each subsequent commit.
- It needs a (single) *tree hash ID* for the source tree to store in the commit.  You'll pick, for each new commit you make, the source tree associated with that day's commit.
- Last, it needs a *commit message*.  You can feed it that day's commit's message.

You may also want to override the default settings for the committer-and-committer-date and author-and-author-date.  You can do all four through six separate environment variables, `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`, and the three corresponding variables with `COMMITTER` in place of `AUTHOR`.  Or, in tcsh/bash brace-expansion syntax, `GIT_{AUTHOR,COMMITTER}_{NAME,EMAIL,DATE}`.  The place to get these values would be the original commits that you're transposing.

Overall, then, your script might look like this:

```
last=$root    # find and set the root commit hash ID

for commit in $(get-list-of-original-commits-to-copy-in-new-order); do
    set_author_and_committer $commit   # set-and-export GIT_{AUTHOR,COMMITTER}_*
    new=$(git log --no-walk --format=%B $commit |
          git commit-tree -p $last ${commit}^{tree})
    last=$new
done
git branch rewrite $last
```

(untested, and you'll need to write a few functions).  The `git log --no-walk --format=%B` extracts the original commit message in the form `git commit-tree` needs, and `git commit-tree` reads the commit message from stdin by default, so there's no special work here.  We just provide the (singular) parent hash ID via `-p` and the tree hash via the symbolic method of specifying the tree associated with the commit being copied (see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)).

The code to set and export the `GIT_*` variables can be found in [the old `git filter-branch` script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-filter-branch.sh).

Note that this script wrecks any GPG signatures in the commits; handling them requires something much fancier.

Comment: Great thanks! The script works as expected and I could use filter-branch or interactive rebase to fix the rest as long as the tree is correct.